# Git: change upstream repository to other hosting provider

Tags: git

My firm is planning to move from one git host to a new git host... what are the steps I have to take to move my code?

can I just do a "git pull" and then "git push" to the new host?

Answer (score 6):

You might want to change the `origin` remote (the default one) to correspond to the new hosting provider (that way, you won't push to the old one by mistake):

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin <url here>
```

You can get more details on the [manual for git-remote](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html)